# what does readonly means before getter while it also have a setter

Tags: c#, .net

I pressed F12 by mistake on `Point` type and I saw something like:

```
public int X
{
    readonly get => x;
    set => x = value;
}
```

I'm not getting this, I know that `X` is not readonly here, also if it was going to be read-only there shouldn't be a setter.

what does `readonly get` mean?

Can anybody tell me what the above getter and setter mean?

**Update:** from the link on Guru's answer. it says:

> Readonly can be applied to some auto-implemented properties, but it won't have a meaningful effect. The compiler will treat all auto-implemented getters as readonly whether or not the readonly keyword is present.

if it has no effect, why to put it there in the first place.

Comment: Something related to the fact that Point is struct?

Comment: @Steve point is a struct, Ok, but what readonly get means?

Comment: `readonly get => x;` is not an auto-implemented property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C# 8 you can mark members of `struct`'s as `readonly` to signify that they do not change it's state. This is used to prevent hidden copies from happening in case of `struct` used with `in` modifier:

> This normally doesn't have much impact, except in the case of `in` parameters. With `in` parameters for non-readonly structs, the compiler will make a copy of the parameter for each instance member invocation, since it cannot guarantee that the invocation does not modify internal state.

For example as it used in [`System.Drawing.Point` struct](https://source.dot.net/#System.Drawing.Primitives/System/Drawing/Point.cs,61).

Read more in [Readonly Instance Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/readonly-instance-members) specification.